# unable to add a role to a member property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to grant users a role once they submit a form but I am getting this in nodejs

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
```

I have the code set up like this:

```
const guild = discordClient.guilds.cache.get('1234567890');
const member = await guild.members.cache.get('22222222')
const role = await guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '111111');
member.roles.add(role);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add some log statements to check what `guilds` actually looks like. I'm guessing it's having a fit at the `await guild.roles.cache.find...` and so you will probably need to either figure out why and/or add error handling for guilds without roles.

Comment: I am getting the guild info and everything here

Comment: member is coming as undefined though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/) before asking questions. Anyways the answer would be

```
let guild = client.guilds.cache.fetch('id');
const role = await guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'ROLEID');
const member = await guild.members.fetch(req.user.discord_id);
member.roles.add(role);
```

as seen [here on the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch)

Comment: I have read the docs and tried it multiple times, now it works =). I updated your answer with full code and changed guild to guilds

Answer (score 2):

Try using this declaration for the guild.

```
const guild = message.guild;
```

Comment: I am not trying to use it with message, I am trying to call it using an api =)